# Вывод полей ACF с двухуровневой таксономией

Tags: wordpress, acf

Всем привет!

У меня установлен плагин ACF Pro версии и я пытаюсь решить следующее:

У меня есть таксономия в двух уровнях

```
Country 1
— City 1
— City 2
Country 2
— City 1
— City 2
— City 3
etc
```

Для целей SEO это именно таксономии и при заведении материалов в них обязательно надо указывать как страну, так и город. В админке это легко решено плагином https://wordpress.org/plugins/yummi-auto-check-parent-category-category-tree-checklist/

Но вот при выводе формы ACF во фронте я не понимаю как это реализовать?
Вывести ли два поля динамически и связанных? Не получается т.к. можно лишь указать условие выбора верхнего уровня, вывалив вообще все города со всех стран во второй, что не верно.

Comment: Каким образом  формы ACF (и вообще - какие формы у ACF, да ещё на фронте?) связаны с таксономиями?

Comment: У ACF есть функционал форм, он позволяет делать формы во фронте https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/
Как связаны с таксономиями? Есть поле Таксономия у ACF.